# Need help to create complex yaml with python

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have the following code

```
name = "testyaml"
version = "2.5"
os = "Linux"
sources = [
     {
          'source': 'news', 
          'target': 'industry'
     }, 
     {
          'source': 'testing', 
          'target': 'computer'
     }
]
```

And I want to make this yaml with python3

```
services:
   name: name,
   version: version,
   operating_system: os,
   sources:
     -
      source: news
      target: industry
     -
      source: testing
      target: computer
```

I need a help specially on Sources part that how I can add my dictionary list there

Comment: What have you figured out for the rest, besides `sources`? Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import yaml

name = "testyaml"
version = "2.5"
os = "Linux"
sources = [
    {"source": "news", "target": "industry"},
    {"source": "testing", "target": "computer"},
]

yaml.dump(
    {"services": {"name": name, "version": version, "os": os, "sources": sources}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `yaml` module allows you to dump dictionary data into yaml format:

```py
import yaml

# Create a dictionary with your data
tmp_data = dict(
    services=dict(
        name=name,
        version=version,
        os=os,
        sources=sources
    )
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('my_yaml.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(tmp_data, f)
```

Contents from the yaml:

```yaml
services:
  name: testyaml
  os: Linux
  sources:
  - source: news
    target: industry
  - source: testing
    target: computer
  version: '2.5'
```

Comment: would you please see my question and see the specially the sources that how I want to show that is something specially, I already using the above code. If you see my yaml example there is '-' and then in new line the source and target appears

Comment: I see @UmarDraz. The following answer provided some direction to me – but I cannot find a good solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284819/3786245

Comment: I think it is quite difficult, and there is no clue around

Comment: You could write your own encoder...