# How to add blank lines before list blocks with python yaml.dump (pyyaml)

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a complex yaml document which gets rendered as

```
interfaces:
  - name: phy-1_1_1
    description: 'Ansible: cfg phy-1_1_1'
    breakout: to-four
  - name: phy-1_1_2
    description: Interface phy-1_1_2
    admin_status: down
  - name: phy-1_1_3
    description: Interface phy-1_1_3
    admin_status: down
...
```

The output is not very human friendly when the yaml file grows big.

**How can we add an empty linebreak after/before each `list` blocks** i.e. obtain following

```
interfaces:
  - name: phy-1_1_1
    description: 'Ansible: cfg phy-1_1_1'
    breakout: to-four

  - name: phy-1_1_2
    description: Interface phy-1_1_2
    admin_status: down

  - name: phy-1_1_3
    description: Interface phy-1_1_3
    admin_status: down
...
```

Inspired from `https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/127` (which addresses a similar problem with toplevel objects), I tried fiddling with yaml dumper class, but could not come up with anything fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

cf answers from [Formatting PyYAML dump() output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14228915/6885397).

To summarize, there are 3 options:

1. Post process the produced yaml and parse it according to your own preferences. This can give something like the following (adapted from [the accepted answer of the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561170/6885397) to use `re` module instead of plain `str.replace`):

   ```
   import re, yaml

   stream = yaml.safe_dump(
       your_data, indent=4, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False, width=math.inf
   )
   main_keys = re.compile(r"(\n\w+)")
   next_blocks = re.compile(r"(?<!:)(\n {0,6}- )")  # only first and second level list elements here + exclude the first elements (that directly follow the list's name (and colon) )
   double_newline = lambda m: f"\n{m.group(1)}"  # noqa: E731
   stream, _n = re.subn(main_keys, double_newline, stream)
   stream, _n = re.subn(next_models, double_newline, stream)

   with open(your_output_yml_path, "w") as f:
       f.write(stream)
   ```
2. Use another (more fruitfully maintained) library for yaml IO. Something like [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) suggested as [the second most popular option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694748/6885397).
3. Subclass `yaml.Dumper` like shown on [the third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284819/6885397) or on [this comment](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/127#issuecomment-525800484) from the pyyaml issue 127.

Comment: Rereading the title, I guess the second option might not be an option for you 